# Rendering Result varies vastly from what I see in the viewport when using Texture coordinate's "Generated"

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to get more into procedural texturing, and I found myself facing a problem where the texture I'm seeing in my viewport is diffrent from what is rendered. While trying to fix the problem, I narrowed the "root of evil" down and I'm now actually pretty certain that the "Generated" output of the Texture coordinate is causing me problems.
I am unable to think of what could cause this or how to fix it.
Maybe this is normal when using this output and I never noticed, wouldn't make any sense to me tho?! Is it some Camera settings I'm too dumb to spot?
I'm rendering in Cycles btw and attaching some photos of my viewport and the rendered result, as well as one of the node tree.
[image: This is what the texture looks like in the iewport]
[image: This is the Node tree]
[image: An this is my result if rendering]

Hope someone could provide any help to solve the problem :)

[image] Here's the blendfile

Comment: just a wild guess: are there any modifiers on the object that have different settings for the viewport and rendering?

Comment: Hi Niklas, as you can see with Blunder's comment -> we can only guess because you didn't provide us all necessary informations to help you. So pls provide your blend file so we can check it out. And no - i am pretty sure it is not the generated coordinate, else everybody would complain about it.

Comment: @RobinBetts I uploaded the blend file now. Hope it helps

Comment: @Blunder no not as far as I'm concerned. I do use subd, but the levels for viewport and render are the same.

Comment: @Chris I see. just thought it had something to do with the generated one, since it was the only input coordinate that changed it. MAy my blendfile helps now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem. I'm using a surface deform modifier on this object, and every node connected to a generated coordinate is rendered with a different result.
In the Shader preview the nodes/ the whole texture is applied after all the modifiers, but when rendered the surface deforme is taken into accountance after the texture is applied. I did not now that, and that caused me the trouble.

Thanks to everyone trying to help.